# Add-Member in PowerShell Workflow

Tags: powershell

I have the following workflow in PowerShell:

```
workflow Audit-Computer
{
    param([string[]]$Computers)

    foreach -parallel ($computer in $Computers)
    {
        #Create a return object to hold the information we gather
        $returnObject = [PSCustomObject]@{ComputerName=$computer}

        #Test if the machine is reachable 
        $hostAlive = $true
        try {
                #Attempt a connection to the computer.
                $os = Get-WmiObject –class Win32_OperatingSystem -PSComputerName $computer –erroraction Stop

                #If we get here the connection was successful 
                $returnObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HostAvailability" `
                    -Value "Online" -PassThru | `
                        Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OperatingSystem" -Value $os.Caption
        } catch {
                $hostAlive = $false
        }

        if($hostAlive){
            #The host is alive lets run our audit
        }
        else
        {
            $returnObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HostAvailability" -Value "Offline"
        }

        #Return the gathered information to the pipeline
        Write-Output $returnObject       
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the Add-Member does not seem to work. The object returned does not contain the NoteProperties from add-member. How do I add properties to my custom object in a workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several restrictions on cmdlets in PowerShell Workflows. According to [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions.aspx), `Add-Member` is restricted to "local execution only".

I'm not able to test your script exactly, but this seemed to reproduce the same effect:

```
workflow Test-Workflow {
    $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{ComputerName = 'test'}
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name HostAvailable -Value "Online"
    Write-Output $obj
}
```

but adding an `InlineScript` block made it work:

```
workflow Test-Workflow {
    InlineScript {
        $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{ComputerName = 'test'}
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name HostAvailable -Value "Online"
        Write-Output $obj
    }
}
```

Comment: I see your point and spotted the article shortly after I posted. It definitely seems hard to return sensible output from a workflow.